# How can I capture Mouse Events (mouseDown and mouseUp) on an NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, events, mouse, mousedown, mouseup

This is what I wnat to do and I couldn't yet.
Hope you can help me.

I have a button and a table. And I want to edit table content when I press this button.
When I press my button in a mouseDown event I want to capture that event and, let's say, get the actual time. And when I release the button in a mouseUp event I want to get que actual time again and update a row in my table.

For example:
1- Press button (with out releasing it, capture mouseDown event): get actual time, let's say: 18:10:23.
2- Release button (capture mouseUp event): get actual time, let's say: 18:10:33.
3. Update my table:

```
-------------------------            -------------------------
|_#_|__start__|___end___|    ==>     |_#_|__start__|___end___|
| 1 |00:00:00 |00:00:00 |            | 1 |18:10:23 |18:10:33 |
-------------------------            -------------------------
```

How should I do this?
My principal problem is that NSButton doesn't capture both mouseDown and mouseUp event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mouseDown: you fetch events until you see a corresponding mouseUp event.

Here’s a [blog entry](http://alastairs-place.net/blog/2007/11/19/commands-and-mo/) with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
 {
       [_myButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
 }
```

and using what wil said